# Java regex with a positive look behind of a negative look ahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract from this kind of string `ou=persons,ou=(.*),dc=company,dc=org` the last string immediately **preceded by** a coma **not followed by** (.*). In the last case, this should give `dc=company,dc=org`.

Looking on regex, this seems to be a positive look behind (preceded by) of a negative look ahead.

So I have achieve this regex: `(?<=(,(?!.*\Q(.*)\E))).*`, but it returns `,dc=company,dc=org` with the coma. I want the same thing without the coma. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I have solved my problem alone, removing the capturing group around the negative look ahead. It gives the following regex: `(?<=,(?!.*\Q(.*)\E)).*`.

It is linked with the behavior of capturing groups in look arounds as explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html in the part *Lookaround Is Atomic*.

Answer (score 3):

The comma appears because the capturing group contains it.

You can make the outside capture group noncapturing with `(?:)`

```
(?<=(?:,(?!.*\Q(.*)\E))).*
```

Comment: Thanks. It works so I accept your answer. As you can see, I have solved my problem myself in another way, achieving the same reasoning on capturing groups.

Comment: I prefer your answer :)