# How do regex positive look-behinds work?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been solving old question from stack so that I can improve my regex knowledge. As I have a basic knowledge of regex, most of them were easy but this question [regex problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814421/java-regex-with-a-positive-look-behind-of-a-negative-look-ahead) is tough.

**It asks for a regex that extracts from this kind of string `ou=persons,ou=(.*),dc=company,dc=org` the last string immediately preceded by a comma not followed by `(.*)`. In the last case, this should give `dc=company,dc=org`.**

The solution is `(?<=,(?!.*\Q(.*)\E)).*` but I cannot understand its flow. I understood `(?!.*\Q(.*)\E)` portion but other are still mystery to me. Specially `?<=` which is a positive look-behind. Does it search from end of string?  Can anyone explain it to me like I am a 7 year old kid — and please http://regex101.com/ is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

The RegEx `(?<=,(?!.*\Q(.*)\E)).*` look-behind potion works like this:

1. **Start at the beginning** of the string at first character.
2. **Can we match the the thing we are looking for?** `,(?!.*\Q(.*)\E)`
3. - **If we can't**: Move forward one character, **Go To `2.`** and check match again.
   - **If a match is found**: Capture all the remaining characters until we can't find any `.*` (or generally then try the matching the remaining RegEx).

For a more wordly explaination consider reading [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can it be solved using lookahead??

Comment: That is best asked in another stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

A lookbehind allows you to specify a context just before the actual match.

You can say `,(dc=)` and only return the capture group, or `,\Kdc=`, or `(?<=,)dc=` to return the match on `dc=` but require that the comma is present just before the match.

The facility also allows for multiple lookbehinds, so you could do `(?<=a.*)(?<=b.*)c` to match `c` only if it is preceded by both `a` and `b` somewhere in the input.

A lookbehind is basically syntactic sugar, in that you can usually rephrase your conditions using some other regex construct. It can be really handy when you have multiple unanchored constraints, like in the last example